# Definition of a project-scratch-def for E&U features (Cloud, Self-Service Portal & Sales Digital)

Tags: scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, energy-and-utilities

I'm trying to generate a proper scratch org with the following definition. So far I have not been able to make it work, does somebody already experienced this error ?

```
  "orgName": "POCEUC",
  "country": "FR",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "adminEmail": "alexandre.s@example.com",
  "features": ["Communities", "EnergyAndUtilitiesCloud","EAndUSelfServicePortal", "EAndUDigitalSales"],
  "hasSampleData": true,
  "settings": {
      "communitiesSettings":{
          "enableNetworksEnabled": true
      },
      "lightningExperienceSettings": {
          "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
      },
      "mobileSettings": {
          "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
      }
  }
}
```

Apparently the features are not reconciled:
[image: Warning message: features]

Would you know what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks,
Alexandre S.